# How to update status with conflict data where chemical temp table have same chemical Id on temp table #temp?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

How to update status with conflict data where chemicalId on temp table #chemical have same chemical Id on temp table #temp ?

steps to achieve that

1- get related parts to part exist on temp table #temp that have same masked id on temp table #parts

in this case result will be

```
PartId  MaskId   ChemicalId
200     1000     901
500     1700     909
600     1700     909
```

2- check on temp table #chemical for partid or related part id for same maskId

if chemicalid on step 1 different to chemicalid on temp table chemical
then nothing happen on status .

if checmicalid on step 1 same chemicalid on temp table chemical 
then status will updated to conflict based on part id .

Here 200 have 901 chemical id on temp table #temp and on chemical temp table have 901 for 100
then status will be conflict because it related to same mask id and have same chemical id 901 .

Here 700 have 909 chemical id on temp table #temp and on chemical temp table have 909 for 500 and 600
then status will be nothing changed because it related to same mask id and have different chemical id 920.

```
create table #temp
(
partid     int,
maskid     int,
chemicalid int,
status  nvarchar(50)
)
insert into #temp
values
(100,1000,901,null),
(700,1700,909,null)

create table  #parts
(
PartId  int,
maskId  int
)

insert into #parts (PartId,maskId)
values
(100,1000),
(200,1000),
(500,1700),
(600,1700),
(700,1700)


create table  #Chemical
(
Chemicalmasterid  int,
ChemicalId  int,
PartId   int
)                        
insert into  #Chemical(Chemicalmasterid,ChemicalId,PartId)
values
(1 ,901,100),
(7 ,920,700)

final result
100     1000 901 conflict chemical id
700     1700 909     null
```

what i have tried

```
update t set status ='conflict chemical id' from #temp t
```

Comment: Your logic is really hard to follow.  Is there anything you can do to clarify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic is quite convoluted, but you do give sample data and intermediate results.

I think I understand what you are trying to do.  I think this query does it:

```
update t
    set status ='conflict chemical id'
    from temp t join
         parts p
         on p.maskid = t.maskid and
            p.partid <> t.partid join
         chemical c
         on c.partid = t.partid
     where exists (select 1 from chemical c where c.partid = t.partid and c.chemicalid = t.chemicalid);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb2a37fce22a5420ae7dc1204842ce01) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you for reply this is actually what i need but can you give me solution done above using left join and where condition without using exist or not exists or this not possible meaning i need to achieve that by using query. and i dont need to use subquery as above

Comment: @ahmedbarbary . . . If this solve your problem, I see no need for a `left join`.